# Clarification on "polynomial over a field"

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I found this text from Hoffman & Kunze book (section 7.5):

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are polynomials over $F$, a subfield of the complex numbers. We may also regard $f$ and $g$ as polynomials with complex coefficients. The statement that $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime as polynomials over $F$ is equivalent to the statement that $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime as polynomials over the field of complex numbers. We leave the proof of this as an exercise.

So, different questions arise.

  i. When we say "a polynomial over a field $F$" that means the coefficients and domain of the polynomial are over the field $F$ right? So for example $f(x) = x+2$ and $g(x) = x+2i$ are polynomials over the complex numbers and we may set $x$ to $5i+2$

  ii. What am I supposed to prove here? that if a polynomial is defined over a subfield of $F$ then is also defined over $F$? or the roots are the same?

Sorry for the mess, I am trying to study on my own but this book is particularly confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

When we say that $f$ is a polynomial over the field $F$, it means that the coefficients of $f$ are elements of $F$, and we write $f(x) \in F[x]$.

It seems to me that you are confusing the term “polynomials” and “polynomial functions”. A polynomial function is a function $$p:x \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k,$$ with a given domain. On the other hand, a polynomial is a *infinite series* of the form $$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n+...$$ where $x$ doesn’t have a given value (it is called a indeterminate.) You can see a polynomial as a linear combination of the elements of the infinite set $B=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n,...\}$. In fact, $B$ is the canonical basis of the vector space $F[x]$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: Does, "over $F$," additionally connote that linear combinations of the polynomials are restricted to those coefficients that are elements of $F$?

Comment: A polynomial is (characterized by) a *sequence* of coefficients that is **eventually zero**. E.g. the expression $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n$ lies in $F[[X]]$, not in $F[X]$. As you say, monomials are an $F$-basis for $F[X]$, so elements are a *finite* linear combination of monomials.

Comment: @guidoar, that went right over my head. Can you answer yes or no to my request for more information?

Comment: @MichaelLevy sorry, I was actually commeting on something James wrote: a polynomial is a **finite** sum of monomials $a_i x^i$. As you say, "over $F$" means the coefficients of the polynomial are elements of $F$. "A polynomial over $F$" is the same as "an element of $F[X]$".

Comment: @guidoar. Thank you. That much I get. One last time: When we say, "$f$ and $g$ are polynomials over $F$," does that connote that we can only consider combinations of $f$ and $g$ with coefficients in $F$.  For example, if $F =\mathbb{R}$ and I add $i\,f + (-i)\,g$; have I violated the premise that "$f$ and $g$ are over $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: No: "$f$ and $g$ are over $\Bbb R$" only indicate that $f$ and $g$ have real coeffcients.  Here's an example of how one may use the phrase: "since $f = X^3+2$ and $g = X^4+280$ are polynomials over $\Bbb Q$, we know that $h = \sqrt{2}f+\pi^2g$ is a polynomial over $\Bbb R$, hence $h(0)$ cannot be imaginary"

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial is not the polynomial function that it defines, over a finite field, two distinct polynomials may be associated to the same function example $X^p-X$ is zero over the finite field with $p$ elements.

Here si $F[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]$ are PID, you have to show that  $f=pq$ $deg(P)>1, deg(q)>1$ in $F[X]$, it is equivalent that $f=p'q', deg(p)>1, deg(q)>1$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$.